# CodeRunner type of plugin/library on ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, coderunner

I need a way to implement something like CodeRunner on Moodle, but on ASP .NET Core application. Is there a way to do that, some plugin or library?

I tried CodeRunner on Moodle, but it needs a Moodle application to run it. I need a way to implement it in ASP .NET Core application.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for software libraries is off-topic on stackoverflow because it is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic